# Math: Formula to scale a number to another number

Tags: javascript, math

I asked a similar question earlier today, and it turns out that I just suck at math, because I can't figure this one out, either.

I'm calculating the screen ratio via width/height. I need a function to convert that resulting number to a new scale.

e.g.

```
function convertNum(ratio) {
  return //formula here
}
```

Examples:

```
Given a resolution of 3000x1000 = ratio of 3 (i.e. 3000/1000).
I want it converted to 133.3 via the function, e.g. convertNum(3) spits out 133.33

2500x1000 = 2.5 (desired result: 100)
2000x1000 = 2   (desired result: 66.6)
1500x1000 = 1.5 (desired result: 33.3)
1000x1000 = 1   (desired result: 0)
```

It should keep scaling this way for all screen ratios above 1.0.

Comment: "I want it converted to 133.3" --- where did the `133.3` come from?

Comment: @danh It's a variation on this technique: http://andyshora.com/css-image-container-padding-hack.html

I'm giving assets proper padding for various resolutions. The ratios seem to scale linearly with the desired results. So every 0.5 ratio bump results in 33.3% additional padding.

Comment: @daveycroqet So `((ratio - 1) / 0.5) * 0.333`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yup, you got it. Submit as an answer!

Comment: @daveycroqet Check my updated answer. It can actually be simplified quite a bit further and made more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an additional 33.3% for every 0.5 in the ratio.

First figure out how many "padding pieces" you need to add:

```
// Subtracting 1 since 1 should result in a 0
(ratio - 1) / 0.5
```

Then multiply the number of padding pieces by the padding amount:

```
((ratio - 1) / 0.5) * 0.333
```

But dividing by 0.5 is the same thing as multiplying by 2, so it can be further reduced down to:

```
(ratio - 1) * 2 * 0.333
```

But that's obviously the same as:

```
(ratio - 1) * 0.666
```

Although, you could get more precision by changing that to:

```
(ratio - 1) * (2 / 3)
```

Comment: This was a very thorough breakdown and I appreciated it tremendously. I'm not sure why my brain was incapable of deciphering this math because you made it look so simple!

Comment: @daveycroqet A large part of writing code is figuring out small math equations. If you practice it, you'll get better over time. I like to draw things out. Even if it's not a visual problem, just seeing *something* tangible helps. Having a folded piece of graph paper and a pen beside you while you write can encourage it. Reviewing basic algebra is really helpful too, even if you've studied it before.